# Show Nest Camera video within Android WebView

Tags: nest-api

Im trying to show embedded video within Android WebView, but currently i have nothing but a plain white screen.

This is a code provided from Nest for embedded video:

```
"<iframe type="text/html" frameborder="0" width="480" height="394" src="//video.nest.com/embedded/live/Es9Ol5DCCB?autoplay=1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is how I'm trying to use in im my app:

```
 WebView webview = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);//new 
    WebView(view.findViewById(R.id.camera_view));
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    String html = "<iframe type=\"text/html\" frameborder=\"0\" width=\"480\" height=\"394\" src=\"//video.nest.com/embedded/live/Es9Ol5DCCB?autoplay=1\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("video.nest.com",html, "text/html", null, null);
```

Am i missing some permissions here?

Comment: I figured it out. It just needed a fully qualified url. after replacing this line:webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https:\/\/video.nest.com",html, "text/html", null, null); everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to render videos from Nest camera with the following code.

First of all please make sure public_share_url is enabled for your camera.

Instead of loading URL in iFrame I have used video url directly.

```
String iFrameUrl =
"https://video.nest.com/embedded/live/Es9Ol5DCCB?autoplay=0";

WebSettings webViewSettings = webView.getSettings();
webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webViewSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); webView.loadUrl(iFrameUrl);
```

Happy coding!